# What is the intuition behind my Residual vs Time Plot having the same structure as my Data vs Time Plot in a Time series

Tags: time-series, residuals

If I ran a regression on time series data and found the residuals over time and plotted this graph and it looks exactly like the pattern of the original data itself - what is the intuition behind this? Does this mean the model has failed to capture the trend or succeeded? Unable to grasp the intuition behind this.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern of the innovations explains perfectly the movement of the whole time series (also extent of movements) then you failed to capture anything. Why? Because for a good fit, the remaining innovation in the residuals should be as small as possible and further, it should definitely not be essential to describe the data. In general, you predict by leaving the innovations out and just use your estimated coefficients and the regressors (in TS-context lags). Try that and compare it to the data.

Comment: btw are you using a lasso regularization? This might explain what you observe.